# Am I on the right track with correcting this tub drain issue?

Tags: plumbing, framing

Tub drain over joist

Looking to resolve this issue: tub drain set directly above the joist and I do not want to notch it - 1) not my place 2) that joist has been wet for a while.

There is a Jack supported center beam that runs perpendicular to the joists just out of frame to the right that the joists sit on.

My plan is to do what the third picture shows and cut the water impacted joist at 16” and 40” from the center beam. Attach the remaining joist to doubled up headers and sister the remaining complete joists on either side. Everything tied in with 2x8 joist hangers.

The box in the center will be roughly 24”x31” Because the headers will be in the way of the drain, I’m thinking I’ll just have to drop it below the level of the joists?.[image: drain on top of joist so drain does not sit flush]

Comment: There are not 3 pictures, and it's unclear what you mean by "not my place" - if you rent, make the landlord call a plumber, if something else, please [edit] to clarify. The one picture *seems to show* a tub drain with leaks set beside, not "directly over" a joist. Fixing the leaks is what's needed. A joist that's merely been wet can dry out - it's not clear that it's rotten and needs to be cut out.

Comment: Under the IRC, you can cut a 1/3-joist-depth hole if you keep it 2" from the top and 2" from the bottom. 7.5"/3 = 2.5". Heading off joists, a single header is sufficient for up to 4'-0" length. All that said, I'd sooner sister a joist to the other side of the slightly damaged joist than I would frame that opening. I second @Ecnerwal, though. FYI, the hole size and header length are all in the neighborhood of [IRC R502.10](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-5-floors#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.10).